# Comprobar la existencia de un archivo

Tags: c#, sqlite

Este es mi problema, en c#, el código genera archivos txt, estoy creando un panel de control que verifica la creacion de estos txt, con 1 que si existe y 0 que no existe, el problema que se me presenta es que una vez que finaliza en verificar la creacion de los txt, en cada actualizacion duplica esa verificacion

es por ello que pense que eso podria ser controlado, si verifico la existencia de ese archivo (codigo) en la tabla EstadoProceso que tengo. Como puedo capturar ese registro para luego compararlo con los registros que ya exiten en la tabla (EstadoProceso), y si existe que lo actualice caso contrario que lo adicione, eso debo de realizarlo en c#?, por favor necesito de vuestra ayuda, gracias.

//AQUI ES DONDE GENERO LOS TXT

```
string IDRepEstadoProceso = lcFactura.RucEmisor + "-" + lcFactura.TipoDocumento + "-" + lcFactura.SerieFactura + "-" + lcFactura.NumeroFactura;
                        estadoProceso = new ENT_EstadoProceso
                        {
                            ID = IDRepEstadoProceso,
                            Fecha = DateTime.Parse(lcFactura.FechaFactura),
                            Sucursal = lcFactura.CodSucursal
                        };
                        //crea base de dtos
                        //insertantdo el primer registro
                        repEstado.SaveEstadoProceso(estadoProceso);
                        // 12 .- GENERAR TXT DE CABECERA
                        String lcNombre = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cfSalidaTXT"]
                                                + "CAB-"
                                                 + lcFactura.TipoDocumento
                                                 + "-" + lcFactura.SerieFactura /// jjj
                                        + "-" + lcFactura.NumeroFactura
                                                + lcAnio
                                                + lcFactura.CodEmpresa
                                                + lcFactura.CodSucursal
                                                + ".txt";

                        System.IO.File.Delete(@lcNombre);
                        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@lcNombre, true))
                        {

                            String lcLineaCab =
                                // DATOS FACTURA
                                lcFactura.TipoDocumento + "\t" +
                                lcFactura.SerieFactura + "\t" +
                                lcFactura.NumeroFactura + "\t" +
                                lcFactura.FechaFactura + "\t" +


                            file.WriteLine(lcLineaCab);
                            file.Close();
                        }
                        //VERIFICADOR DE CREACION GENTXT 1
                        estadoProceso.ID = IDRepEstadoProceso;
                        estadoProceso.GenCABTXT = 1;
                        repEstado.CabeceraOK(estadoProceso);
```

//
//MI TABLA EstadoProceso la Cree en esta clase

```
   private static void CreateDatabase()
    {
        using (var cnn = SimpleDbConnection())
        {
            cnn.Open();
            cnn.Execute(
                @"create table Seguimiento
                  (
                     ID                                  integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,
                     RUC                                 varchar(15),
                     cpTipo                              varchar(2),
                     cpComprobante                       varchar(100) not null,
                     cpDescripcion                       varchar(100) not null,
                     cpEstado                            varchar(100) not null,
                     cpFecha                             datetime
                  )");
            cnn.Execute(
                @"create table EstadoProceso
                  (
                        ID               varchar(28) NOT NULL,
                        Fecha            datetime,
                        Sucursal         varchar(10),
                        GenCABTXT        int,
                        GenDETTXT        int,
                        GenXML           int,
                        GenFirmado       int,
                        GenZIP           int,
                        GenSUNAT         int,
                        GenEnviadoMail   int,
                        GenFTP           int,
                        RutaRespuesta    varchar(250)
                  )");
        }
    }
```

//Aqui cree el objeto EstadoProceso

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Gem.DataAccess.Entity
 {
    public class ENT_EstadoProceso
    {
       //ID integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,
       public string ID { get; set; }
       public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
       public string Sucursal { get; set; }
       public int GenCABTXT { get; set; }
       public int GenDETTXT { get; set; }
       public int GenXML { get; set; }
       public int GenFirmado { get; set; }
       public int GenZIP { get; set; }
       public int GenSUNAT { get; set; }
       public int GenEnviadoMail { get; set; }
       public int GenFTP { get; set; }
       public string RutaRespuesta { get; set;}
   }
}
```

Comment: Subí tu porción de código que realiza ese proceso. Saludos

Comment: Karen es necesario que compartas lo que has hecho hasta el momento como así también la estructura de tu tabla para poder ayudarte. Cuanta más información brindes, más precisa será la ayuda que se te pueda brindar.

Comment: Karen, ¿has usado el método [File.Exists()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.90).aspx)?

Comment: Como determino si esiste en mi tabla Estado proceso, por favor?

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza el metodo File.Exists (String)

```
string curFile = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(curFile) ? "File exists." : "File does not exist.");
```

Deberías de utilizar mejor stored prodcedures en lugar de código c# en la aplicación.

Comment: como determino si existe en una tabla, por favor?

Comment: En SQL o en donde?

Comment: Estoy trabajando c# con sqlite

Comment: Me servio para saber si existe y ahora como puedo saber si tiene contenido ?